Clickable link (hyperref) in a plotly table without the use of dash
Is there a way to create a clickable link in a plotly table without using dash?
The following code shows the links but they are not clickable.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Link': ['<a href="https://www.google.com>Google</a>', '<a href="https://www.youtube.com>YouTube</a>'],
    'Name': ['Google', 'YouTube'],
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['Link', 'Name']),
    cells=dict(values=[data['Link'], data['Name']])
)])
fig.show()

